# Representation of Hilbert transform by a singular integral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integral-transforms

Hilbert transform defines as follow:

> $$ H: L^2(\mathbb R) \to L^2(\mathbb R) $$
>
> $$ H(f)= \mathcal{F}^{-1}[{F(\gamma) \mathrm{sign}(\gamma)]}$$
>
> Where $F(\gamma)= \mathcal{F}(f) (\gamma)= \hat f$ is the fourier transform of $f(x)$, and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(F(\gamma))$ is the inverse fourier transform.

I want to check that Hilbert transform can be represented as a singular integral as follow:

> $$ H(f)= -\frac{1}{i \pi} \,\,\,p.v.\int_{|x-y|>\epsilon} \frac{f(y)}{x-y} \, \mathrm{d}y = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x-y|>\epsilon} \frac{f(y)}{x-y} \, \mathrm{d}y $$
>   which the above limit is taken in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ space.

My approach:

I define

$$H_{\epsilon}(f)= \frac{-1}{i \pi} \int_{|x-y|>\epsilon} \frac{f(y)}{x-y} \, \mathrm{d}y $$

which using convolution, it can be rewritten as follows:

$$ H_{\epsilon}(f)=\frac{-1}{i \pi} (f * g_{\epsilon}), $$

$$g_{\epsilon}(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{y} & |y|>\epsilon\\ 0 & |y| \leq \epsilon
\end{cases}$$

So $$ H_{\epsilon}(f)= \frac{-1}{i \pi} \mathcal{F}^{-1} \big( \hat f \hat g_{\epsilon} \big) $$

Calculating the Fourier transform of $\hat g_{\epsilon}$ we can conclude:

> $$ H_{\epsilon}(f) = \frac{1}{\pi} \mathcal{F}^{-1} \bigg( \hat f(\gamma) \int_{|y|>2 \pi \epsilon} \frac{\mathrm{sin}(\gamma y)}{y} \, \mathrm{d}y \bigg) $$

I should now show that 
\begin{equation}
\label{eq}
\| H_{\epsilon}(f) - H(f) \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \to 0 \quad \mathrm{as} \quad  \epsilon \to 0
\end{equation}

but I only know that

\begin{equation}
\label{eq2}
\int_{|y|>2 \pi \epsilon} \frac{\mathrm{sin}(\gamma y)}{y} \, \mathrm{d}y \to \pi \,\, \mathrm{sign(\gamma)}  \quad \mathrm{pointwise \,\,\, as} \quad  \epsilon \to 0
\end{equation}

My Question is this:

How can I show $H_{\epsilon}(f)$ converge to $H(f)$ in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ sence.

My attempts is as follow:
Using Plancheral Identity

$$ \| H_{\epsilon}(f) - H(f) \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}=\| \hat{H_{\epsilon}(f)} - \hat {H(f)} \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} $$

So

$$ \| H_{\epsilon}(f) - H(f) \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}= \| \frac{1}{\pi} \bigg( \hat f(\gamma) \int_{|y|>2 \pi \epsilon} \frac{\mathrm{sin}(\gamma y)}{y} \, \mathrm{d}y \bigg)- \hat f(\gamma) \mathrm{sign}(\gamma)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$$

Hence it suffices to show that
$$ \bigg\| \hat f(\gamma) \bigg(\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{|y|>2 \pi \epsilon} \frac{\mathrm{sin}(\gamma y)}{y} \, \mathrm{d}y - \mathrm{sign}(\gamma)\bigg)\bigg\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}  \to 0 $$
as $ \epsilon \to 0 $

Comment: Hint: dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Fan Zheng: Can you help How Can I use the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: The multiplier is uniformly bounded and converges pointwise.

Comment: @ Fan Zheng: But domain is unbounded, it seems for me that uniformly boundedness does not say anything

Comment: @ Fan Zheng: Do you mean that I break the real line to two pieces and use dominated convergence for the bounded one and show that the other one is small?

Comment: $\hat f$ times a uniformly bounded multiplier is dominated by $C\hat f$, which is square integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in many classical references where the Hilbert transform is defined one way and the other derived (and vice-versa). Take a look at [this note, page 42-](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~chou/notes/harmonic.pdf) and reverse the argument shown there. An excellent reference is:

Elias Stein, *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions*, Princeton Univ. Press, 1970.